# Tensorflow inference upto logits layer - for batches on pre-trained model

Tags: python, tensorflow, inference

I am trying to run inference on a dataset I have (`X_train`) and get the value of the logits layer without the softmax applied to the output. The model I load from a checkpoint file (`model_X.ckpt`) has the logits layer named "logits". So basically, I want to run:

```
sess.run("model_X/logits:0", feed_dict: {"Placeholder:0": X_train, keep_prob:1.0})
```

But the model restricts the input dataset size to 32, which doesn't let me pass 10,000 inputs at once. This is why I also use batch creation as such:

```
features_placeholder = tf.placeholder(X_train.dtype, X_train.shape)
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((features_placeholder))
dataset = dataset.batch(32)
```

I create an iterator (using one-shot-iterator explodes my graph size, purely based on my reasoning):

```
def initialize_iterator(sess, iterator, features):
    sess.run(iterator.initializer, feed_dict={features_placeholder: features})

iterator = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
initialize_iterator(sess, iterator, X_train)
next_x = iterator.get_next()

# Assign the first batch:
val = sess.run(next_x)

layer = "model_X/logits:0"
units = sess.run(layer,feed_dict={"Placeholder:0": val, keep_prob:1.0})
```

How do I iterate over all the batches to infer over all the inputs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to iterate over all the batches, for a dataset size of 100k and a batch size of 32 (3125 iterations), I just had to do:

```
def body(sess, batch, arr):
    val = sess.run(batch)

def getActivations(sess,layer,stimuli,labels):

    units = sess.run(layer,feed_dict={"Placeholder:0": np.reshape(stimuli,[32,64,64,3]), keep_prob:1.0})
    return units

    try:
        res = getActivations(sess,"model_X/logits:0",val)
        arr = np.append(arr, np.reshape(res,[32,1024]), axis=0)
    except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
        print("End of dataset")  

    return arr, pred

with tf.Session() as sess:

    load_graph(sess)

    initialize_iterator(sess, iterator, X_train)
    next_x = iterator.get_next()

    arr = np.empty((0,2048), int)

    for i in range(0,3125):
        arr = body(sess, next_x, arr)
```